# How to change a Facebook page URL a second time

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Facebook allows to change the Facebook Web Address once if you `enter in your Facebook page` > `About` > `Page info` > `Facebook Web Address`.

Facebook does not allow to do it a second time. I have found a "trick" to do it, though it does not seem safe. The trick is merging it to a new page: http://www.customgrowthgroup.com/how-to-change-your-facebook-page-vanity-url-for-the-2nd-3rd-or-x-time/

Do you know if it is safe? Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is safe, but Facebook most likely has checks to prevent abuse like this. By circumventing Facebook restrictions technically you are breaking TOS and risk losing your page entirely.

Be sure to review

- https://www.facebook.com/terms
- https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php